# my wordpress page visual compser only loading but not working

Tags: wordpress

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwoaT.jpg)I am new to WordPress. For the last 3 days I am trying to fix this problem , but I can't solve it. My WordPress page visual composer is not working it only loads but does not work. [Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q39Nc.jpg)

Comment: Impossible to answer to something like this. I mean think yourself... What do you expect us to say?

Comment: see the screenshot , and try to solve this problem

Comment: As said: completely impossible. You see, we are really good. Indeed. But we are not that good that we can somehow magically guess your code.

Comment: Please read this before asking questions here, thanks: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Update your `Visual Composer Plugin` to the latest version available, its code compatibility issue with your `Wordpress` version installed.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your WordPress doesn't support the code generated by visual composer all you need to do is head towards plugin section and hit the update button. Secondly always use latest theme and plugin version to pretend yourself from hacking. All the best.